# when nusoap is calling a web service from PHP application, handling timeout issues

Tags: nusoap

I am using nusoap in my PHP application when calling a .net webservice.

The issue is, in some cases .net web service is taking more than actual time for some request, so I want to increase the time my SOAP call waits for the response.

Is there any function or any way that I can keep nusoap call waiting until I get a response from the webservice.

Thanks,
Rama

Answer (score 6):

Nusoap default timeout is 30 secs.

Increase Response timeout to solve this problem.

```
// creates an instance of the SOAP client object
 $client = new nusoap_client($create_url, true);

// creates a proxy so that WSDL methods can be accessed directly
$proxy = $client -> getProxy();

// Set timeouts, nusoap default is 30
$client->timeout = 0;
$client->response_timeout = 100;
```

Note : This settings also didn't work for some time. So i directly went to **nusoap.php** file and changed $response_timeout = 120. By default this value set to 30 secs.

It is solved now :)

References : [Time out settings](http://geodata.grid.unep.ch/webservices/table_values_request.txt) - [Second reference](http://www.oos-shop.de/doc/nusoap/html/class_8soapclient_8php-source.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you create the istance of the nusoap_client try

```
$client = new nusoap_client($$creat_url, true,false,false,false,false,0,300);
```

where all the false parameters default to false,
0 is the timeout and 300 is the response_timeout

Thanks